# Eliminar elemento de un array bidimensional

Tags: laravel

Mantengo el siguiente arreglo bidimensional obtenido de la base de datos MYSQL en una consulta para el armado del menú dinámicamente, pero necesito ubicar el elemento que mantiene permiso = 'opcion_referidores' para su posterior eliminación de todo este sub arreglo dentro del arreglo principal

```
array:1 [▼
  0 => array:10 [▼
  "id" => 9
  "menu_id" => 0
  "nombre" => "Comercial"
  "url" => "#"
  "orden" => 7
  "icono" => "fa-check-square-o"
  "permiso" => "menu_comercial"
  "created_at" => "2019-09-26 10:28:33"
  "updated_at" => null
  "submenu" => array:2 [▼
    0 => array:10 [▼
    "id" => 31
    "menu_id" => 9
    "nombre" => "Referidores"
    "url" => "users/referidores"
    "orden" => 6
    "icono" => null
    "permiso" => "opcion_referidores"
    "created_at" => "2019-09-27 15:13:40"
    "updated_at" => null
    "submenu" => []
  ]
  1 => array:10 [▼
    "id" => 35
    "menu_id" => 9
    "nombre" => "Clientes"
    "url" => "users/clientes"
    "orden" => 10
    "icono" => null
    "permiso" => "opcion_clientes"
    "created_at" => "2019-09-27 15:14:21"
    "updated_at" => null
    "submenu" => []
     ]
    ]
  ]
]
```

Comment: Muestra lo que has intentado y con que problemas/errores te encontraste. No creo que alguien vaya a escribir tu código por tí

Comment: utilizo la instruccion array_search($line['permiso], $menuAll, 'permiso'),  pero no funciona, devuelve false el momento de buscar el $key para eliminar el array().  De igual he buscado en varios sitios el tema de eliminar item de array y ya he probado algunos pero no funciona ninguno...

Answer (score 0):

Lo que haría, sería aprovechar los [métodos](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#available-methods) de las colecciones de Laravel. Hay varias combinaciones que se pueden hacer. Te paso un ejemplo con map y where.

Para este array:

```
$array = [
    "id" => 9,
    "menu_id" => 0,
    "nombre" => "Comercial",
    "url" => "#",
    "orden" => 7,
    "icono" => "fa-check-square-o",
    "permiso" => "menu_comercial",
    "created_at" => "2019-09-26 10:28:33",
    "updated_at" => null,
    "submenu" =>  [
        [
            "id" => 31,
            "menu_id" => 9,
            "nombre" => "Referidores",
            "url" => "users/referidores",
            "orden" => 6,
            "icono" => null,
            "permiso" => "opcion_referidores",
            "created_at" => "2019-09-27 15:13:40",
            "updated_at" => null,
            "submenu" => [],
        ],
        [
            "id" => 35,
            "menu_id" => 9,
            "nombre" => "Clientes",
            "url" => "users/clientes",
            "orden" => 10,
            "icono" => null,
            "permiso" => "opcion_clientes",
            "created_at" => "2019-09-27 15:14:21",
            "updated_at" => null,
            "submenu" => [],
        ]
    ]
];
```

Lo que hago es mapear los elementos y para el caso del elemento que tiene como llave `'submenu'`, solo devolver los sub elementos donde el valor para la llave `'permisos'` es distinto de `'opcion_referidores'`.

```
$array_filtrado = collect($array)->map(function ($item, $key) {
    if ($key == 'submenu')
        return collect($item)->where('permiso', '<>', 'opcion_referidores')->values();
    return $item;
})->toArray();
```

Lo que resulta en:

```
[
    "id" => 9,
    "menu_id" => 0,
    "nombre" => "Comercial",
    "url" => "#",
    "orden" => 7,
    "icono" => "fa-check-square-o",
    "permiso" => "menu_comercial",
    "created_at" => "2019-09-26 10:28:33",
    "updated_at" => null,
    "submenu" => [
        [
            "id" => 35,
            "menu_id" => 9,
            "nombre" => "Clientes",
            "url" => "users/clientes",
            "orden" => 10,
            "icono" => null,
            "permiso" => "opcion_clientes",
            "created_at" => "2019-09-27 15:14:21",
            "updated_at" => null,
            "submenu" => []
        ]
    ]
]
```